# TFS how to make quick code changes for production without undoing current changes

Tags: tfs

I'm not sure how to explain this question but I do know it's possible for what I want to achieve, I'm just not sure how to to it.

Lets say I'm working on a lengthy project in one of my solutions and the deadline isn't for a few more months but also need to make a changes to the same solution for some minor changes to go out into production before the other project is due. Obviously the code that's due for the project in a few months can't go out into to production because it could be catastrophic.

What's the best way to accomplish that? Would that be considered branching?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's a branch.

Create a "hotfix" branch from the code that's currently running on production, fix the issue, check in and merge the changes back to "trunk", possibly upmerging the change to other branches (such as the one you're working on).

Of course the absolute quickest way would be to fix it on the "trunk" or main/head branch, but it sounds like you're already developing on that one.